# Proving equality / binomial coefficient

Tags: real-analysis, binomial-coefficients

Prove

$\frac{1}{2^{2n}} \binom{2n}{n} = \frac{1  \cdot 3 \dots (2n-1)}{2 \cdot 4 \dots (2n)}$

I know that $\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}=\frac{(n+1)\cdot(n+2)\dots (2n)}{n!}$

However after that I do not know what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use the double factorial notation:
$$(2n)!!=2\cdot4\cdots(2n-2)\cdot2n$$
$$(2n-1)!!=1\cdot3\cdots(2n-3)\cdot(2n-1)$$
Clearly, $$(2n)!=(2n)!!(2n-1)!!\tag1$$
Also, we see that $(2n)!!=2^nn!$ so $(1)$ becomes $$(2n)!=2^nn!(2n-1)!!\tag2$$  Divide both sides of $(2)$ by $(n!)^2$ to get $$\binom{2n}n=\frac{2^n(2n-1)!!}{n!}$$ and now dividing both sides by $2^{2n}$ gives $$\frac1{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^nn!}=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$$ which is the formula we were asked to prove.

Comment: Thank you. I somehow knew that it has to be solved with the double factorial but was not sure. Thank you for your solution

Comment: @galaxy-- My pleasure.